# Partial deserialization of JSON object by using DataContractJsonSerializer

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, datacontractserializer, datacontractjsonserializer

As a response from a Bitbucket REST API I'm getting the following JSON object (simplified version):

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "scm": "hg",
            "has_wiki": false,            
            "language": "c#",
            "slug": "Repo1"
        },
        {
            "scm": "hg",
            "has_wiki": false,            
            "language": "java",
            "slug": "Repo2"
        },
        {
            "scm": "hg",
            "has_wiki": true,            
            "language": "c#",
            "slug": "Repo3"
        }
    ],
    "user": {
        "username": "someuser",
        "first_name": "Some",
        "last_name": "User",
        "display_name": "Some User",
        "is_team": false,
        "avatar": "https://someuseravatar.com",
        "resource_uri": "/1.0/users/someuser"
    }
}
```

The only part from this JSON object I need to be deserialized is a `user` part. For that purposes I created the following class:

```
[DataContract(Name="user")]
public class BitbucketUser
{
    [DataMember(Name = "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "first_name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "last_name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "display_name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "is_team")]
    public bool IsTeam { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "avatar")]
    public string Avatar { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "resource_uri")]
    public string ResourceUri { get; set; }
}
```

And a helper method to deserialize json:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
    {
        T result = (T)deserializer.ReadObject(stream);
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, when I'm trying to get deserialized `User` object by using this code:

```
User user = JsonHelper.Deserialize<User>(jsonResponse);
```

Then I'm getting `user` object created containing all properties as `null`. I have tried to find right attributes to use on class header, but the result is same. And also I'm not using a Json.NET library just to avoid extra library reference as well as I'm not creating wrapper class to hold that user object as property of `User` type and repositores object as a array of the Repositories[] type.
Is there a solution for this issue to get deserialized user object without null fields ?

Comment: “I'm not using a Json.NET library just to avoid extra library reference” Is that library reference really something to avoid? Even Microsoft now distributes some of its libraries through NuGet.

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm this is how to do it with newtonsoft.json (got this question as first on google, so it might be useful for others)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work, because the JSON object you're deserializing doesn't have any of the `User` properties. The deserializer certainly won't try looking into children of the current object to see if something matches.

What you should do is to create a type that represents the whole response object. If you're not interested in the `repositories` part, then just omit it.

The following code works for me:

```
[DataContract]
public class BitbucketResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name="user")]
    public BitbucketUser User { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BitbucketUser
{
    [DataMember(Name = "username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    // etc.
}

…

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(BitbucketResponse));
using (var stream = …)
{
    var response = (BitbucketResponse)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    var user = response.User;
}
```

Comment: This is the only way to achieve the goal without any third party libraries.

Comment: @Arterius I believe it's probably possible using JavaScriptSerializer with customt type mappers which wouldn't require third party libraries, but this should do the trick anyway

Answer (score 0):

I am writing a code for you it will help you to deserialize the object from json to yourClassCustomObject.

```
private async Task<List<BitbucketUser>> MyDeserializerFunAsync()
{
    List<BitbucketUser> book = new List<BitbucketUser>();
    try
    {
       //I am taking my url from appsettings. myKey is my appsetting key. You can write direct your url.
       string url = (string)appSettings["mykey"];
       var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
       request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
       var factory = new TaskFactory();
       var task = factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(request.BeginGetResponse,request.EndGetResponse, null);
       var response = await task;
       Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
       string data;
       using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
       {
           data = reader.ReadToEnd();
       }
       responseStream.Close();
       DataContractJsonSerializer json = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<BitbucketUser>));
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
       book = (List<BitbucketUser>)json.ReadObject(ms);
       return book;
   }
}
```

Above code is working in my wp8 application it is faster you can try, it will help you. I am performing asynchronous operation but you can create your simple method with BitbucketUser return type.

Comment: But the JSON is not an array of users, so I think this code won't work.

Comment: but your json is following the standard format of json, right ? if yes than it will work. I think you should try once. Your try will help to correct myself, if this code will not work in your case.

Comment: It's not “my” JSON, I'm not the one who asked the question. But like I said, the JSON posted in the question is not an array of users, so I don't see how this code could work.